# What's wrong on this trigger creation?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRIGGER_HYPDM_TDC_MONITOR_ANAG
BEFORE INSERT ON HYPDM_TDC_MONITOR_ANAG REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD 
FOR EACH ROW 
WHEN (:NEW.RICHIESTA_ID IS NULL)
BEGIN

  SELECT SEQ_HYPDM_TDC_MONITOR_ANAG.NEXTVAL
    INTO :NEW.RICHIESTA_ID
    FROM dual

  :NEW.CREATION_DATE := SYSDATE;
END;
```

This is the error:

```
    16:30:02  [CREATE - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 25000, SQL State:     99999]  ORA-25000: uso non valido della bind variable nella clausola del trigger WHEN
 16:30:02  [END - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 900, SQL State: 42000]  ORA-00900: istruzione SQL non valida
```

Seems like something about the "WHEN" condition....

Comment: `new` pseudo-record  should be referenced in the `WHEN` clause of a trigger without semicolon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Try this

`CREATE TRIGGER TRIGGER_HYPDM_TDC_MONITOR_ANAG
BEFORE INSERT ON HYPDM_TDC_MONITOR_ANAG REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD 
FOR EACH ROW 
WHEN (NEW.RICHIESTA_ID IS NULL)
BEGIN
  SELECT SEQ_HYPDM_TDC_MONITOR_ANAG.NEXTVAL
    INTO NEW.RICHIESTA_ID
    FROM dual
  NEW.CREATION_DATE := SYSDATE;
END;`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood the error message, it claims that a wrong binding variable has been used. This might be a result of using ":new" instead of "new", since usually : indicates binding variables.